# jsonschema not validating missing required properties

Tags: node.js, validation, jsonschema

I know this question pops up quite a bit and I have tried researching the issue before posting but still do not know what I am missing

I have a schema with nested objects. My schema is expecting a `company` property to be an object. There are required properties on that object, but they are being ignored. Why is it ignoring the required properties?

Schema:

```
{
        'business_type': {
            'type': 'string',
            "enum": ['company', 'non_profit']
        },
        'email': {
            'type': 'string'
        },
        'company': {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'address': {
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                        'city': {
                            'type': 'string',
                        },
                        'country': {
                            'type': 'string',
                            'enum': ['US']
                        },
                        'line1': {
                            'type': 'string'
                        },
                        'line2': {
                            'type': 'string'
                        },
                        'postal_code': {
                            'type': 'string'
                        },
                        'state': {
                            'type': 'string'
                        }
                    },
                    'required': ['city', 'country', 'line1', 'postal_code', 'state'],
                },
                'name': {
                    'type': 'string'
                },
                'phone': {
                    'type': 'string'
                }
            },
            'required': ['address', 'name', 'phone'],
        },
        'required' : ['business_type', 'email', 'company']
    }
```

Example object that does not fail but should because it is missing the phone property

```
{
    "business_type": "company",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "company": {
        "address": {
            "city": "city",
            "country": "US",
            "line1": "line1",
            "line2": "line2",
            "postal_code": "00000",
            "state": "AZ"
        },
        "name": "name"
    }
}
```

The validation works fine if it is missing either business_type, email, or company so it's not validating the nested structure.

I'm assuming I'm overlooking something, I just don't know what it is I'm overlooking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap `business_type`, `email`, and `company` in a `properties` keyword.  Otherwise the schema doesn't consider them to be properties, just extra data in the schema.  JSON Schema will ignore keywords it doesn't know.

You have it correct in the `company` subschema.

Comment: I knew it must have been something minor, I was focused on the issue being in the nested structure.